# How do you localize MudBlazor DataGrid in Blazor WebAssembly?

Tags: localization, blazor, mudblazor

I'm working on a Blazor (.NET 7) webassembly app using MudBlazor components and was wondering how and if it's possible to localize f.ex the DataGrid for "is-IS"?  I have already done the basic localization using .resx files.

I created a WebAssemblyHostExtension and reference it in Program.cs and that works just fine using IStringLocalizer but MudBlazor components are just in english.  What am I missing?

```
builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();

var host = builder.Build();
await host.SetDefaultCulture(); // Retrieves local storage value and sets the thread's current culture.
await host.RunAsync();

 public async static Task SetDefaultCulture(this WebAssemblyHost host)
    {
      

        CultureInfo cultureInfo;

        try
        {
            var localStorage = host.Services.GetRequiredService<ILocalStorageService>();
            var cultureString = await localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("culture");

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cultureString))
            {
                cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(cultureString);
            }
            else
            {
                cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(LocalizerSettings.NeutralCulture.Name);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex
        {
            cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(LocalizerSettings.NeutralCulture.Name);
        }

        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
    }
```

Comment: It looks like it is not possible in the current version, but it is an known issue for some time. [Linke1](https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/discussions/6148#discussioncomment-5710286) [Link2](https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/issues/6099)

Comment: Well, then I will have to taka a look at the Syncfusion DataGrid.  I was wanting to stick to MudBlazor.

Answer (score 1):

in blazor wasm hosted **client** project:

1. Add these lines to **program.cs** :

   CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
   builder.Services.AddTransient<MudLocalizer, DictionaryMudLocalizer>();
2. Add BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData with true value to the .csproj file of client project in **PropertyGroup** section:
   BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData>true</BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData
3. create a DictionaryMudLocalizer class :

   public class DictionaryMudLocalizer : MudLocalizer
   {
   private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _localization;

   ```
    public DictionaryMudLocalizer()
    {
        _localization = new()
        {
            { "MudDataGrid.Unsort", "حذف سورت" },
        };
    }

    public override LocalizedString this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            _localization.TryGetValue(key, out var res);
            return new(key, res);
        }
    }
   ```

   }

**to make it use the custom localizer, the CurrentUICulture can't be any of the english cultures**

https://mudblazor.com/features/localization#dictionary-based-example

Comment: What if we want to use resx based localiztion. I tried and I failed:
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77424957/mudblazor-data-grid-localization-using-resource-files-in-blazor-server-app)