# How to change the unsort label in MudDataGrid?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, blazor, mudblazor

I want to use MudBlazor app on different language. Can`t find a way to change text of label Unsort.
[label to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORUNr.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76143041/how-do-you-localize-mudblazor-datagrid-in-blazor-webassembly It looks like it cannot be done easily

Answer (score 1):

This label hardcoded in:
\MudBlazor\Components\DataGrid\HeaderCell.razor

```
...
<MudMenuItem Disabled="@(_initialDirection == SortDirection.None)" OnClick="@RemoveSortAsync">Unsort</MudMenuItem>
...
```

Only way to change it is to change the sources.